# Maven skip tests

Tags: maven

I am using Maven 2.2.1 and to build my project I used this command

```bash
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

However, the build failed saying it couldn't find one of the artifact. However, when I used:

```bash
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

everything worked fine.

So far I have been thinking that these 2 commands are equivalent. However, [this link](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) seems to suggest that `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` also skips compiling the test cases.

However, that still didn't explain to me why one command is working and another is not. Will be thankful if anyone please explain this to me.

Comment: What version of maven-surefire-plugin are you using? Is it the same as doc version you're reading?

Comment: One skips building, the other skips running. If you want both use both.

Comment: Can you provide details of the failure - the error message or stacktrace?

Comment: Why are you using such an older Maven version which is [already defined EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html).

Comment: So is it really true that to completely skip everything test related I have to use `-Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests`? One or the other can sometimes be omitted, depending on the circumstances, but who wants to think about that..

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If you set `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` you prevent building and also running, since something that has not been built can not be run.

Comment: @DavidBalažic True, how short-sighted of my comment 3 years ago.

Answer (score 269):

As you noted, `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` skips compiling the tests. More to the point, it skips building the test artifacts. A common practice for large projects is to have testing utilities and base classes shared among modules in the same project.

This is accomplished by having a module require a `test-jar` of a previously built module:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.myproject.mygroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>common</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` (or simply `-Dmaven.test.skip`) is specified, the `test-jar`s aren't built, and any module that relies on them will fail its build.

In contrast, when you use `-DskipTests`, Maven does not **run** the tests, but it does compile them and build the test-jar, making it available for the subsequent modules.

Comment: How to solve this problem? As my online maven command use -Dmaven.test.skip.

Comment: @neptune what problem? If you have a new question, please use a new post to ask it.

Comment: The `<classifier>tests` is missing at your dependency. See [Default Artifact Handlers Reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.2/maven-core/artifact-handlers.html).

Answer (score 129):

I had some inter-dependency with the tests in order to build the package.

The following command manage to override the need for the test artifact in order to complete the goal:

```
mvn -DskipTests=true  package
```

And also you can use the below command :-

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: Just `... -DskipTests ...` on the cmd line is sufficient.

Comment: @GeroldBroser in some cases it is not sufficient to skip the test cases

Comment: @MuhammedFasil Can you elaborate such cases? [Maven Surefire Plugin / Skipping Test](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html#Skipping_Tests) supports my view.

Comment: @GeroldBroser in case your tests have compile errors, `-DskipTests` would make the build fail, whereas `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` passes due to the skipped test compilation

Comment: @SebastianSaip That's right. Perhaps there was a misunderstanding. I meant in my original comment that `=true` isn't needed (at both, according to [Mureiniks top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30275449/1744774)). I didn't mean that there is no difference between them function-wise.

Answer (score 104):

There is a difference between each parameter.

- The `-DskipTests` skip running tests phase, it means at the end of this process you will have your tests compiled.
- The `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` skip compiling and running tests phase.

As the parameter `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` skip compiling you don't have the tests artifact.

For more information just read the surfire documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html

Answer (score 41):

To skip the test case during `mvn clean install`, I used `-DskipTests` parameter in the following command

```
 mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

in the terminal window.

Comment: `-DskipTests` doesn't skip just _the_ test case. It skips _all_ test cases.

Answer (score 21):

I can give you an example which results in the same problem, but it may not give you an answer to your question. (Additionally, in this example, I'm using my Maven 3 knowledge, which may not apply for Maven 2.)

In a multi-module maven project (contains modules `A` and `B`, where `B` depends on `A`), you can add also a *test dependency* of `A` in `B`.

This dependency in `B` may look as follows:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
     <artifactId>A</artifactId>
     <classifier>tests</classifier>
     <type>test-jar</type> <!-- I'm not sure if there is such a thing in Maven 2, but there is definitely a way to achieve such dependency in Maven 3. -->
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

(For more information refer to https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html)

Note that project `A`usually produces a secondary artifact with a classifier `tests` (i.e. `.../com/foo/A/<version>/A-<version>-tests.jar`) where the test classes and test resources are located inside.

If you build project `A` with `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, you will get a dependency resolution error when building `B` unless `A`'s *test artifact* is found in your local repo or remote repositories. The reason is that the test classes of `A` were neither compiled nor the `tests` artifact of `A` was produced.

However, if you build `A` with `-DskipTests` its `tests` artifact will be produced (though the tests won't run) and the dependency in `B` will be resolved successfully.

Answer (score 18):

The parameter -DskipTests may not work depending on your surefire-plugin version.

> You can use "-Dmaven.test.skip.exec" instead of "-DskipTests"

Source: [Surefire Parameter Details](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skipExec)

Comment: Thanks. `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip.exec` command worked for me.

Comment: [`<skipExec>`/ `maven.test.skip.exec`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skipExec) is "_**Deprecated**. Use skipTests instead._".

Answer (score 10):

I have another approach for Intellij users, and it is working very fine for me:

1. Click on the "Skip Test" button

[image]

2. Hold the "CTRL" button
3. Select "clean" and "install"

[image]

4. Click on the "Run" button in the maven pannel

[image]

Comment: 'Install' phase includes 'test' so this approach does not exclude tests.

Comment: @EduardStreltsov when you click on the "Skip Tests" button you'll se that the "test" step is excluded

Comment: forgot about skip tests button, my bad. Checked, it works

Comment: This answers just half of the question: the `-DskipTests` part, doesn't it?

Comment: @GeroldBroser No, when you use this method, you don't need the -DskipTests part, intelliJ will handle it :)

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi That's what I meant: These IntelliJ settings are like `-DskipTests` behind the scenes, aren't they? But there's also `Dmaven.test.skip=true` in the question.

Answer (score 9):

For the fastest build, to skip both compiling the test files and running the tests:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip
```

From the [Maven Surefire Plugin docs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html):

> ... you can also use the maven.test.skip property to skip compiling the tests. maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire, Failsafe and the Compiler Plugin.

Even more ways to speed up installing can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514457/1636613) to the question "[Ways to make maven build faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368976/ways-to-make-maven-build-faster)".

Answer (score 7):

During maven compilation you can skip test execution by adding following plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
         <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It skips tests even when you do `mvn test`

Comment: I do not recommend this (apart from special environments, e.g. having production code and test code in two different projects). Maven's default, its convention, is to run (unit) tests during a build. With that you override this default behaviour for no good reason. Use the command line property instead or use a build profile (if you really must) named `skipTests` that sets the property and is activated via `mvn ... -PskipTests ...` on the cmd line or via one of the other [activation methods](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Answer (score 4):

With latest version of Maven

The way of giving command bit change.

below command will works perfectly

```
mvn clean install "-Dmaven.test.skip=true"
```

Comment: This is not "_With latest version of Maven_". This exists since v2.0 of the Maven Compiler Plugin. We're at v3.8.1 now.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following for skipping both compiling and running tests (maven 3.8.1) :

```
mvn install  -Dmaven.test.skip.exec -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: [`<skipExec>`/ `maven.test.skip.exec`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skipExec) is "_**Deprecated**. Use skipTests instead._".

Comment: For my case  skipTests did not work. Only the flags I have used in my answer worked. It may be because of maven version.

Answer (score 0):

It should be mentioned that `maven.test.skip` mentioned in a few answers herein also skips the `default-testResources` execution:

```
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ project ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ project ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
...
```

whereas `maven.main.skip` of [`compiler:compile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#skipMain) doesn't do that with `default-resources`:

```
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ project ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ project ---
[INFO] Not compiling main sources
[INFO] 
...
```