# project module are getting skipped in night build configuration

Tags: maven, jenkins

Kindly note: "I have edited this question"
I am observing a very strange situation. I have 2 jobs configured in Jenkins having same configuration except that one of them is continuous build and another is nightly build [ poll scm configured @midnight] with Sonarqube configuration to generate report.

Both builds have same Repository URL and Both of them are having build result success. But in continuous build, every modules is analysed and then getting success. whereas in nightly build, modules are skipped. 
what my question is same build is running fine for continuous build and not for nightly. so what could be cause of this ?

Earlier i was using `-DskipTests` which was analysing all module and getting successful in continuous build.. but was skipping in nightly build. 
so i refered this link [Maven skip tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727536/maven-skip-tests]) and added `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`  in maven goals.. and now some of the modules are analysed and getting success. But one fo the module got failed and due to which other modules got skipped. below is the error log

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
>   (default-test) on project ASData: There are test failures.

Note: I am using maven 3.3.1 version and SonarQube 5.1

Comment: Are they related to each one? Do the jobs use different workspaces?

Comment: what do you mean by "one of them is continuous build and another is nightly build"? How exactly to you differentiate between both? Profiles? Goals?. It might be useful to provide the config.xml for both jobs.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji No.. there are not related to each other.. they just have same repository url. and yes.. both jobs use different workspace.

Comment: @blackbuild it means that.. for nightly build.. we have added Poll SCM for build trigger at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not allowed to add comments so I will ask here.

Where do you keep the modules and can you guarantee that noone will severe the connection between your build and the storage of modules?