# Docker instruction in Java Maven project to skip tests

Tags: maven, docker

I am in my Maven based Java project.  I want to skip the tests when building the Java project.

Currently, I have the following Docker instructions

```
RUN ["mvn", "clean"]
RUN ["mvn", "install"]
```

How do I skip the tests in the "install" instruction?
I tried putting `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried putting `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` but didn't work

It depends how you put it. I would try:

```
RUN ["mvn", "install", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true"]
```

Although, do read "[Maven skip tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24727536/6309)" or "[Maven packaging without test (skip tests)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9682198/6309)".