# Can't compile Quarkus (or disable tests?)

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I'm trying to compile Quarkus without the tests, unfortunately I tried:

```
mvn package -Dmaven.repo.local=$out -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

But the tests are still executed… (and fail https://discourse.nixos.org/t/run-a-program-from-maven-using-jbang/20082/2)

**EDIT**

Actually I was thinking that the problem was the tests (because before I got issues with tests so I understood that it compiled), but it may actually be a bug with the compilation, I'm not sure what is test and what is library:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Quarkus - Parent pom 2.10.1.Final:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Quarkus - IDE/Tools - Config ....................... SUCCESS [ 59.572 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Revapi Configuration ..................... SUCCESS [  2.980 s]
[INFO] ArC - Parent pom ................................... SUCCESS [ 16.616 s]
[INFO] ArC - Runtime ...................................... SUCCESS [  5.279 s]
[INFO] ArC - Processor .................................... SUCCESS [  5.247 s]
[INFO] ArC - Tests ........................................ SUCCESS [  1.983 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Bootstrap - Parent ....................... SUCCESS [  0.019 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Bootstrap - BOM .......................... SUCCESS [  0.015 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Bootstrap - Test BOM ..................... SUCCESS [  0.014 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Bootstrap - App Model .................... SUCCESS [  1.176 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Bootstrap - Maven Resolver ............... SUCCESS [  4.765 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Bootstrap - Gradle Resolver .............. SUCCESS [  8.947 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Bootstrap - Core ......................... SUCCESS [  2.002 s]
[...]
[INFO] Quarkus - REST Client Config - Runtime ............. SUCCESS [  1.146 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - REST Client .............................. SUCCESS [  0.029 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - REST Client - Runtime .................... SUCCESS [  1.942 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Undertow ................................. SUCCESS [  0.016 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - Undertow - Runtime ....................... SUCCESS [  1.153 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC parent .............................. SUCCESS [  0.020 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC - API ............................... SUCCESS [  0.569 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC Common .............................. SUCCESS [  0.028 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC Common - Runtime .................... SUCCESS [  1.933 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - SmallRye Stork Integration ............... SUCCESS [  0.018 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - SmallRye Stork - Runtime ................. SUCCESS [  0.728 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC - Protoc Plugin ..................... SUCCESS [  2.126 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC - Code Gen .......................... SUCCESS [  7.716 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC - Stubs for health and reflection ... FAILURE [  4.464 s]
[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC - Runtime ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Micrometer ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Micrometer - Runtime ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Micrometer Registry - Prometheus - Parent  SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Micrometer Registry - Prometheus Runtime . SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - RESTEasy - Common - SPI .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - RESTEasy Reactive - SPI .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Undertow - SPI ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - JSON-P - Deployment ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - RESTEasy - Common - Deployment ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - JAX-RS SPI - Parent ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - JAX-RS - SPI - Deployment ................ SKIPPED
[...]
[INFO] Quarkus - Integration Tests - gRPC - Hibernate ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Integration Tests - gRPC - Hibernate Reactive SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Integration Tests - Helper project containing packaging a proto file for grpc-external-proto-test SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Integration Tests - gRPC - External proto Test SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Integration Tests - gRPC with Stork - gathering response times SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Integration Tests - Google Cloud Functions HTTP SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Integration Tests - Google Cloud Function  SKIPPED
[INFO] Quarkus - Documentation ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  07:13 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-02T07:51:53Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile (compile) on project quarkus-grpc-stubs: An error occurred while invoking protoc: Error while executing process.: Cannot run program "/build/source/extensions/grpc/stubs/target/protoc-plugins/protoc-3.19.3-linux-x86_64.exe": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :quarkus-grpc-stubs
```

Any idea if this is a test or a library that fails? Any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT2**
I'm running the above code on NixOs, maybe it could explain the above error (NixOs enforce purity by moving the linux loader elsewhere). I also asked a question here https://discourse.nixos.org/t/cant-package-quarkus/20085

Comment: Try this one -DskipTests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven skip tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727536/maven-skip-tests)

Comment: @JanB. Thanks, but I already read that question… but in fact I'm even wondering if the problem is really with the tests (the first time I compiled, it actually failed on HTTP tests as I had another server running on the same port, so I tought the compilation was going fine, but maybe not). Do you know if this `[INFO] Quarkus - gRPC - Stubs for health and reflection ... FAILURE [  4.464 s]` is a test or another issue? Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -Dquickly`?

Comment: @geoand yes, I tried `-Dquickly -Dno-test-modules`